# Tornado testing "ioloop is closing" runtime error

Tags: tornado

I have such test. The issue is in comments.

```
@gen_test(timeout=10)
def test_handshake(self):
    print "+++++++++ Test create_stream ++++++++++"
    self.io_loop.current().spawn_callback(self.pool.process_base_channel)
    strcmd = "{'cmd': 'crt_stream', 'p_id':'test_stream','redis_chan':'test_chan'}"
    cmd = ast.literal_eval(strcmd)
    yield self.pool.q.put(cmd)
    yield self.pool.q.join() 
    self.assertIsInstance(self.pool.streams['test_stream'], Stream)

    print "++++++++++ Test subscription ++++++++++++"
    ''' 
       If this blocks run in this function, it OK, but if I move 
       it to separate function, runtime error occurs.
    '''
    subscr = "{'cmd': 'sub2stream', 'stream_id':'test_stream','redis_chan':'test_broadcast', 'cols':'all' }"
    cmd = ast.literal_eval(subscr)
    #self.io_loop.current().spawn_callback(self.pool.process_base_channel)
    yield self.pool.q.put(cmd)

@gen_test(timeout=10)
def test_next(self):
    print "++++++++++ Test subscription ++++++++++++"
    print "Test stream %s" % self.pool.streams['test_stream'].publish_list
    #self.io_loop.current().spawn_callback(self.pool.process_base_channel)
    # tried respawn callbac
    subscr = "{'cmd': 'sub2stream', 'stream_id':'test_stream','redis_chan':'test_broadcast', 'cols':'all' }"
    cmd = ast.literal_eval(subscr)

    yield self.pool.q.put(cmd)
```

For some reasons after test_handshake runs self.io_loop becomes closed. Can't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

With `AsyncTestCase`, each test creates a new IOLoop, and closes it when the test is finished. It looks like you have something (another thread? a destructor? something in your `tearDown` function?) trying to interact with the IOLoop after it is closed, but it's impossible to tell what is going on from this incomplete example (what is `self.pool`?).

Also, you use `self.io_loop.current()` in this code, which is redundant. `current()` is a class method, not an instance method, so it would normally be called as `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()`. In a test, `IOLoop.current()` returns `self.io_loop`, so you can simply use `self.io_loop` instead of `self.io_loop.current()`.

Comment: There is forever async-while (consumer) which runs in background (self.pool.process_base_channel). Pool seted up in setup() of test class. So, when one test closes ioloop, that forever while stil going on and may it cause some "uhoh"?